# How can I restart the "mobile brodband" / modem ? is it possible without restarting the whole system?

Tags: 11.10, mobile-broadband

I have no clue is there anything like I asked or not. I often use Nokia n72 to connect to the Internet. The problem Im facing is, after two or three hrs the modem automatically disconnects.

I can not fix it by restarting the phone. Rather I always had to restart the whole system. Its very annoying. After restart I can reconnect N72 and it works fine. Is there a fix to this ?

Comment: You tried reconnecting your phone after unplugging it, when you get disconnected?

Comment: Yes. it do work sometimes. but most times i had to restart Ubuntu, otherwise the mobile does not shows up on the selection menu.

Answer (score 2):

Install Gnome-ppp from software center

Comment: When i try to install gnome ppp it tries to remove "resolvconf". what "resolvconf" do ? Should i allow synaptic to remove this ?